Does fixing particle number + only evolving to lower energy states make the simulated system isolated?
I'm working on some determinant quantum Monte Carlo simulations. Specifically using the Python package ALF (lattice fermions), which is so cool to work with!
It seems like the method is clearly a quantum system reaching thermal equilibrium in some environment/bath: particle number is not fixed, and it samples from every possible configuration, including with some probability determined by inverse temp those higher energy than the current one
. Earlier I was thinking about whether I could verify the eigenstate thermalization hypothesis and decided probably not because that would require data on an isolated quantum system which these are not. I thought I could constrain my own homebuilt simulation to have fixed particle numbers but there didn't seem to be a way to do it in ALF.
I was reading the documentation about the projective method (as opposed to the main finite-temp method) best for the ground state. Then I came across this sentence: "The finite temperature code operates in the grand canonical ensemble, whereas in the projective approach the particle number is fixed." So, realized that the distinction is grand canonical ensemble vs canonical ensemble where the latter still allows energy in and out of the system. This makes sense!
If I want to simulate an isolated quantum system then, is it true that I have to not only limit the configurations to conserve particle number but also go strictly downwards in energy? My probability distribution is no longer Boltzmann but equally split between all the allowed configurations, those with energies lower than the starting energy?

If a system is completely isolated, then it will neither gain nor lose energy, i.e., its energy is fixed.  A system whose energy is exactly specified will take on states drawn from the microcanonical ensemble.
At least at the classical level, you could sample from this ensemble with an MCMC process if you have an algorithm that can (a) generate an initial state with a desired energy and (b) transition between states in such a way that the energy is conserved.  (Plus some assumptions about ergodicity.)  It would effectively just amount to a random walk in state space, without having to worry about any Boltzmann or Gibbs probability factors.
